# moment-timezone change utc to default timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

Context:

I need to parse datetimes from UTC into the timezone currently set as default by moment-timezone with `moment.tz.setDefault`.

Attempt (functional):

```
const task = {
    startDate: '2020-03-24 14:00:00'
};

const startDateMoment = moment.utc(task.startDate).tz(moment().tz());
```

However, I am creating a new moment object every time I need to set the timezone. Is there a more performant way to converting between utc to the default timezone, or getting the default timezone from moment?

`moment.tz.guess()` guesses the timezone from the browser, not the one set manually.

```
console.log(`default timezone: "${moment().tz()}", guessed timezone: "${moment.tz.guess()}"`);
```

returns

```
default timezone: "US/Samoa", guessed timezone: "America/Vancouver"
```

Comment: You can just use `moment.tz()`, if I'm not mistaken. Otherwise there's [`moment.tz.guess()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/).

Comment: `moment.tz()` creates a new moment object. `moment.tz.guess()` will return the timezone guessed from the browser. I will update the question with this attempt. I need the timezone currently set as default for moment-timezone (the one passed to `moment.tz.setDefault `).

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of digging, I did find the following, *undocumented, **use-at-your-own-risk**, could-disappear-at-any-time* property:

```
moment.defaultZone.name
```

`moment.defaultZone` is a [Zone Object](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/), of which we really only care about the `name` property.

Note that it is null if you haven't set a default yet! In the code below, I'm taking advantage of a couple new JavaScript features, [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [the nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator) to see if the default zone is set and if not, use the `moment.tz.guess()` value.

```js
const task = {
    startDate: '2020-03-24 14:00:00'
};

console.log('before setting default: ', moment.defaultZone);

moment.tz.setDefault('US/Samoa');

console.log('after setting default: ', moment.defaultZone);

const startDateMoment = moment.utc(task.startDate).tz(moment.defaultZone?.name ?? moment.tz.guess());

console.log(startDateMoment.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pretty impressive! As you warned, probably it's something not to use (as it's undocumented and may disappear/change at any time), but it's a very interesting piece of information.